# OpenGL: projecting mouse click onto geometry

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have this view set:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective
```

and I get a screen position (sx, sy) from a mouse click.

Given a value of z, how can I calculate x and y in 3d-space from sx and sy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `gluUnProject`:

First, compute the "unprojection" to the near plane:

```
GLdouble modelMatrix[16];
GLdouble projMatrix[16];
GLint viewport[4];

glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelMatrix);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMatrix);

GLdouble x, y, z;
gluUnProject(sx, viewport[1] + viewport[3] - sy, 0, modelMatrix, projMatrix, viewport, &x, &y, &z);
```

and then to the far plane:

```
// replace the above gluUnProject call with
gluUnProject(sx, viewport[1] + viewport[3] - sy, 1, modelMatrix, projMatrix, viewport, &x, &y, &z);
```

Now you've got a line in world coordinates that traces out all possible points you *could* have been clicking on. So now you just need to interpolate: suppose you're given the z-coordinate:

```
GLfloat nearv[3], farv[3];  // already computed as above

if(nearv[2] == farv[2])     // this means we have no solutions
   return;

GLfloat t = (nearv[2] - z) / (nearv[2] - farv[2]);

// so here are the desired (x, y) coordinates
GLfloat x = nearv[0] + (farv[0] - nearv[0]) * t,
        y = nearv[1] + (farv[1] - nearv[1]) * t;
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob comment. Is the third parameter in gluUnproject calls always same(0 and 1) or does it depend on the zNear and zFar values when we're setting the projection matrix with gluPerspective?