# Make an object clickable (click if the mouse is in the area of object)

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl

I have a rectangle on my window and I am trying to make this rectangle click-able by defining the area of the rectangle.

If the mouse click is inside this area, then it's a click else not.

For eg: On the window, let's assume the vertex of the rectangle is:
`x = 40, y = 50; width = 200, height = 100;`
So, a click will be counted when 
`(mouseXPos > getX()) && (mousxPos < (getX()+width)) && (mouseYPos > getY()) && (mouseYPos > getY()+height)`

Now, I am doing lookAt transformation to the object by inheriting a class which has `lookAt` functions. Also, I am using a camera to check the different faces of the object (camera rotation). So, when the object rotates along various axes and shows different faces when the camera is used.

However, when the object moves, I would have thought the vertices of the rectangle would change. The vertices of the rectangle should also have changed on doing `gluLookAt` function but looks like they do not and my click-area always remains stationary at those points although the object is not there. How do I tackle this problem? How do I make my object clickable and add some mouse events on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to click on 3D shapes, and you are moving the camera, I wouldn't check this in screen coordinates.

Instead, you can project the point where the user has clicked into a line in 3D space, and intersect that against the objects which can be clicked on.

GL has a function for this: `gluUnproject()`

If you give that function the details of your view, along with the screen point being clicked on, it can tell you where in 3D space the user has clicked. If you check a point at both the near and far planes, the line between these points can be checked against your object.

The other alternative, is some kind of ID buffer, where you render the scene off-screen, but instead of outputting shaded pixels, you output ID values for each object. The hit-test is then just a matter of reading a pixel from that buffer.

Comment: Let's say if instead of using the camera, I do the rotation myself using Quaternions or whatever, will in that case I would have the new coordinates?

Comment: If you're doing your own transforms, you would need to either do your own hit-testing, or somehow provide an equivalent transform to GL.

Comment: I am not sure if I am clear about this. Suppose, if I have a `gluSphere` to which I am have applied gluLookAt etc., and then I use a Quaternion to rotate that sphere (or probably translate as well in another operation). In that case, will I be able to get the coordinates by using the inbuilt functions of this object? If I'll be do that, probably hit testing remains something similar to what I wrote in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that nobody else is answering, I will give it a try. :)

Though not very experienced with opengl this seems like the expected behavior to me, and it seems like you are mixing up world coordinates with on screen coordinates.

Think of it this way, if you take a picture of a table in your living room from two different angles it will look differently, but will in both images occupy the same space in that room. The same can be said about entities when working with opengl, even though you move the camera the coordinates for the entity does not change, just the perception of it.

Now, if I'm not mistaken you can translate your world coordinates into on-screen coordinates by applying the same transformations as applied by opengl. I would suggest taking a look at this: [OpenGL: projecting mouse click onto geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113352/opengl-projecting-mouse-click-onto-geometry)

Comment: Let's say if instead of using the camera, I do the rotation myself using Quaternions or whatever, will in that case I would have the new coordinates? OR will it still be the same that you mentioned above/

Comment: If you rotate the entity itself the coordinates will change, but this more of a hack then a solution. And I'm not sure you can guarantee the accuracy of doing this. I think the best solution here would be to follow the solution suggested by openGL. Have a look at these http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/picking.html

Answer (score 0):

Thumbs up for the ID buffer alternative. I used it several times and it was really the right thing to do : no expensive geometry picking and a hardly-total disconnection with the underlying geometry.

Still, you can only pick the closest geometry (that is the one "visible" on the screen) and not the models that could be hidden behind. The same problem appears when dealing with translucent materials too.

One solution could be to do some ID-peeling by rendering four objects in a RGBA ID texture (I have a feeling it could be non-optimal but it's worth a shot).